# How to keep Joomla 2.5 from reinstalling default Templates when updating?

Tags: templates, joomla, content-management-system, default, self-updating

I run several J2.5 Sites. For security reasons i deleted all unused templates.

Whenever i update them, using the built in update tool, the installer seems to reinstall the default frontend and backend templates (atomic, beez_5, beez_20).

Is that an intended behavior or a bug? Can i prevent Joomla from doing so?

Comment: Are you using Joomla's built in 1 click update feature to update it?

Comment: yes i use the com_joomlaupdate which is intercepted by akeeba backup which backups everything before com_joomlaupdate works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the templates are installed every time you update is because they are included in the install package. The install package isn't what you would expect.

If you are updating from (for example) Joomla 2.5.13 to 2.5.24, the zip file that gets extracted doesn't only contain the files that were changed for this specific update. What Joomla does is they have a massive update update zip that contains **all** the updated file since Joomla 2.5 was first released, and they continue adding modified file to this zip file. Admitedly this can be annoying as it makes the zip file that gets extracted on your server quite big, but it also contains **all** the previous updates. So in regards to the template, this was updated at some point (not sure which version the changes were made), which is why the templates get re-installed each time.

Joomla 1.5 was different. They created a separate zip file for each update but it made life very hard as you can not be sure which version they are updating from. So rather than creating lots of different zip files, everything was merged into 1.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So there is no way to stop that behavior i guess (aside from developing a plugin which uninstalls those templates after updating)? Is there an action hook to do that?

Comment: There is no "out-the-box" plugin or anything I can find online. You would have to develop a plugin that extends the update class. Out of all honestly though, it would be easier to manually uninstall them via the Template Manager. Do also bare in mind that Joomla 2.5 reaches end of life and will no longer be supported this December. I believe there is an update coming soon and there may be 1 more after that before December.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, please mark it as solved by click the "tick" icon